# Graph paths even number

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have a Graph which has cities and roads and each road connects 2 cities.You can go from every town to the others but in only one unique way ,and the number of the roads is even number.Prove there is a city from which odd number of roads come out.

Comment: Do you understand what I wrote?

Comment: yes!Any book to reccommend for beginners in graph thoery?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Introductory-Graph-Theory-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486247759/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1420479689&sr=1-1&keywords=chartrand+graph+theory is good cheap and not too advanced, but My favorite is diestel, although it is more advance. Bondy and Murty is also good (but not easy either)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A connected graph is one in which there is a path between any two vertices. A connected graph in which there is exactly one path between any two cities is a tree.Trees have leaves (vertices with degree $1$).Since leaves have odd degree we are done.

Trees which have $n$ cities have $n-1$ edges (this can be proven via induction). We are being told that $n-1$ is even, then $n$ is odd.

There is a result called the handshaking lemma that tells us that the sum of all the degrees in a graph is always even (in fact it is twice the number of edges). Using this result there must be a vertex of even degree since otherwise there would be an odd number of odd degrees, and they would sum an odd number, contradicting the hand shaking lemma.

Thus we have managed to prove there is a vertex with odd degree and there is a vertex with even degree.